# Maintain TimeOverlapping in mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I may not be able to frame a perfect title for my problem definition, but let me try to explain it in detail.

I have 2 MySQL tables, `sessions` and `calendar`.

In sessions table, there are many sessions added by admin, the admin will give session title, date, time and session length.

The user can book any session and hence the calendar for the users gets blocked for that session.

So next time whenever a user goes to book any other session there is MySQL query which checks for his calendar and gives errors there is some other session booked at the time.

The query works perfectly for 95% of the cases, except the one case.

Say, the user already has calendar booked for 1 PM whose length is 60 min i.e 1PM - 2 PM, and then the user goes to book another session which is at 2 PM. In the case expectation as a human is that, it should not be the error. As session1 ending at 2 and session2 will start at 2 PM, but the query shows that I can not book at the time.

Here is my query -

```
SELECT sessionTitle, sessionDate,sessionTime,sessionLength 

FROM calander
JOIN sessions ON `sessionID`=`sessionFID` 

WHERE UserID='14971' AND sessionID != 1128 

AND

 (  
    (
        CONCAT(sessionDate,' ',sessionTime) >= '2018-03-16 12:15:00'
            AND
        CONCAT(sessionDate,' ',sessionTime) < '2018-03-16 13:15:00'
    ) 
    || 
    (
        CONCAT(sessionDate,' ',ADDTIME(sessionTime,SEC_TO_TIME(sessionLength*3600))) > '2018-03-16 12:15:00' 
        AND
        CONCAT(sessionDate,' ',ADDTIME(sessionTime,SEC_TO_TIME(sessionLength*3600))) < '2018-03-16 13:15:00'
    )
   );
```

Please let me know what I am missing in the query.

Please ignore values that I have used in the query.

Thanks,

Comment: what is the error you are getting? please also give us sample data and your expected result when you run the query.

Comment: I notice that in the 'string' version of your time comparison you use >= and in the sec_to_time version you use only >. So this could yield inconsistent results if not all the data is filled in in your tables

Comment: *"Please ignore values that I have used in the query."*  Please edit the question with a verified query that matches what you are asking, and include the row that it finds but should not find.  Please also consider the implications of the inconsistency in your logic as pointed out by @Loopo.